# handle OnCompleted with cold observables

Tags: c#, asynchronous, event-handling, system.reactive

in [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), the following code does not seem to call my OnCompleted action?

### No "Sequence Completed"

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        var obs = list.ToObservable();
        IDisposable subscription = obs.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(p =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        },
        p => Console.WriteLine("Sequence completed"));
        Console.ReadLine();
        subscription.Dispose();
    }
```

Am i doing something silly, as there is no "Sequence Completed" printed after 3 in the Console window?

### Console Output

```
1
2
3
_
```

So, the prime focus of my question is **how to run some code after this type of sequence has been iterated**?

- E.g. how to execute `Console.WriteLine("Sequence completed"))` after all elements in the original list have been *observed*?
- Please note that the `.ToObservable` originated from an `IEnumerable` (a `List<>` in this case)
- And the subscription is run on a `NewThread`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the 2nd parameter to .Subscribe is the error callback. Your "sequence completed" string would be printed only if there was an error observing the elements.

Here's the corrected code:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var obs = list.ToObservable();
var subscription = obs.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(p =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    },
    error => Console.WriteLine("Error!"),
    () => Console.WriteLine("sequence completed"));
Console.ReadLine();
subscription.Dispose();
```

Comment: Perfect! What confused me was that Visual Studio actually showed me the 4th tooltip `Action<TSource> onNext, Action onCompleted` even though I was actually using the 5th overload (i.e. my action syntax was that for error handling) - strange...